# Add standard signature to Outlook Mail with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, signature

I am trying to send an email with Visual Basic, but Outlook removes my signature when creating the mail. 
This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


            Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
            Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

            mailItem.Subject = "Abgabe " + pnamebox.Text + " " + vnummerbox.Text
            mailItem.To = ""
            mailItem.CC = ""
            mailItem.Body = pnamebox.Text
            mailItem.GetInspector.Display()
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal
            mailItem.Display(True)
            mailItem = Nothing
            oApp = Nothing      

    End Sub
```

I am very new to visual basic and appreciate any help.

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly a duplicate of this? [Inserting Signature into Outlook email from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233264/inserting-signature-into-outlook-email-from-excel-vba)

In any case I will note that in my experience, I had to have mailItem.Display be the first thing called in the sequence in order to get the signature to be saved properly. Also setting it to true isn't what makes it visible, that's an option that makes it so you can't click on the Outlook application while the e-mail window is open. Unless you intended to do that, it's probably fine to leave it at the default of false, which lets you click on Outlook while the e-mail window is open.

```
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

dim mySignature as string

with mailItem
.Display 
.Subject = "Abgabe " & pnamebox.Text & " " & vnummerbox.Text
.To = ""
.CC = ""
mySignature = .HTMLBody
.HTMLBody = pnamebox.Text & mySignature
end with
```

Also you'll notice I used HTMLBody instead of Body. If your signature has any kind of formatting in it (most business e-mail signatures I see do) you will want to use HTMLBody to have it retain the formatting. This does mean you might need to add some basic HTML tags around any text you put into the subject to have it show up like you want, but you can do that just by adding them as strings in your HTMLBody

```
.HTMLBody = "<p>" & pnamebox.Text & "</p>" '(etc...)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Was beating my head against a wall to get this done, but the "display first" trick works a treat!