# Inserting my default Outlook Signature into an Email

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to insert my default Outlook signature. I can't seem to get it to work.  Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

I can't seem to get it to work with .HTML

```
Sub Send_email_fromexcel()

    Dim edress As String
    Dim subj As String
    Dim message As String
    Dim outlookapp As Object
    Dim outlookmailitem As Object
    Dim path As String
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim header As String
    Dim header1 As String
    Dim header2 As String
    Dim header3 As String
    Dim header4 As String
    Dim header5 As String
    Dim header6 As String
    Dim header7 As String
    Dim hearder8 As String
    Dim data As String
    Dim data1 As String
    Dim data2 As String
    Dim data3 As String
    Dim data4 As String
    Dim data5 As String
    Dim data6 As String
    Dim sig As String

    x = 2
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) <> ""

        Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)

        edress = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
        subj = Sheet1.Cells(x, 2)
        header = Sheet1.Cells(1, 3)
        header2 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 4)
        header3 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 5)
        header4 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 6)
        header5 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 7)
        header6 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 8)
        header7 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 9)
        header8 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 10)

        data = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3)
        data1 = Sheet1.Cells(x, 4)
        data2 = Sheet1.Cells(x, 5)
        data3 = Sheet1.Cells(x, 6)
        data4 = Sheet1.Cells(x, 7)
        data5 = Sheet1.Cells(x, 8)
        data6 = Sheet1.Cells(x, 9)


        outlookmailitem.To = edress
        outlookmailitem.cc = ""
        outlookmailitem.bcc = ""
        outlookmailitem.Subject = subj
        outlookmailitem.body = "Good afternoon," & vbNewLine & " " & vbNewLine & "I'm just reaching out because we are attempting to process rewards for customers that were referred using the Lawn Doctor Referral Rewards Program,… I have put it in this email." & vbNewLine & "Please update your records accordingly by going into …(s). Please let me know when this has been completed and I will push their Amazon Gift Card out." & vbCrLf & header & " " & header2 & " " & header3 & " " & header4 & " " & header5 & " " & header6 & " " & header7 & " " & header8 & _
        vbCrLf & data & " " & data1 & " " & data2 & " " & data3 & " " & data4 & " " & data5 & " " & data6 & _
        vbCrLf & vbNewLine & "Regards"

        outlookmailitem.display
        outlookmailitem.send

        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        edress = ""
        x = x + 1

    Loop

    Set outlookapp = Nothing
    Set outlookmailitem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233264/inserting-signature-into-outlook-email-from-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. First create a function and then call it in your outlook code just before the email details and when you put the email details do something like  `.HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature`

```
'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Mysig.htm"

    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If


Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Full code as example to make more sense of the above snippet.

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim insertPhoto As String
    Dim photoSize As String
    Dim outlookPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)


    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Mysig.htm"

    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    insertPhoto = "C:\Users\marius.dragan\Desktop\Presale.jpg" 'Picture path
    photoSize = "<img src=""cid:Presale.jpg""height=400 width=400>" 'Change image name here

    emailMessage = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear " & titleName & " " & fullName & "," & _
                    "<p>I hope my email will find you very well." & _
                    "<p>Our <strong>sales preview</strong> starts on Thursday the 22nd until Sunday the 25th of November." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to welcoming you into the store to shop on preview.<p>" & _
                    "<p> It really is the perfect opportunity to get some fabulous pieces for the fast approaching festive season." & _
                    "<p>Please feel free to contact me and book an appointment." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to seeing you then." & _
                    "<p>" & photoSize & _
                    "<p>"


    With outlookMail
        .To = clientEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRIVATE SALE"
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .Attachments.Add insertPhoto, 1, 0
        .HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature 'Including photo insert and signature
        .Importance = 2
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Display 'Needs to display the email and then send to display in line image
        .send 'this will send the email without review

    End With

    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Comment: You cannot concatenate two HTML strings (and emailMessage  above is not even a well formed HTML string) and expect to produce a valid HTML. The two must be merged.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Are you able to elaborate on that statement? It works perfectly the way it is. I’m using this daily and don’t have a problem with it.

Comment: You got lucky that Outlook can handle some misformed HTML. It would not work in general case.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Are you able to share the right way of doing it?

Comment: That would be a few hundred lines of some pretty dense code - you would need to load both message and signature HTML into IHTMLDocument2 object, figure out the attachments in the signature, read them, add as regular attachments to the message and set the content-id appropriately, modify the img tags, merge the HTML styles, then merge the HTML bodies.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Guess I’m just lucky it works right of the box. Please feel free to share this information so others can learn from if you have the time.

Comment: I cannot share that code, sorry - it is a part of a commercial product.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Too bad we could have learned a lot from that.